# Trying to modify state from context consumers, but state is only affected by the last consumer in my template

Tags: reactjs

I have context consumer components which live below a provider component which passes functions down into the context.

I am trying to run a "setup" function from the context which registers a child with the parent by way of the function passed into the context.

What seems to happen is all of the components trigger a state change but only the last component declared in the template has it's changes persist.

Why is that?

Example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-ygwc6v

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is kind of a race condition in your code.

```
  const addItem = (item: string) => {
    setItems([...items, item])
  }
```

This part is being called by 3 different components just after each other. But setting a state is not sequential. 
All three calls are trying to set the state to

```
[...[], 'one']
[...[], 'two']
[...[], 'three']
```

hence you got your result. They all depend on initial state, whereas they should depend on previous state.

Here is the solution:

```
  const addItem = (item: string) => {
    setItems(prevItems => [...prevItems, item])
  }
```

**EDIT**
**- What is happening in first approach?**
React is scheduling 3 setState calls once components mounts. When the components mounts, the items state is []. So all scheduled calls are trying to modify the state with following values:

```
[...[], 'one']
[...[], 'two']
[...[], 'three']
```

Maybe a lifecycle of your components make it more clear:
- render Box
- render Item one
- render Item two
- render Item three
(items state is [] at this point)
- Effect of Item one `setState([...[], 'one'])`
- Effect of Item two `setState([...[], 'two'])`
- Effect of Item three `setState([...[], 'three'])`
- Items state changes to `[...[], 'one']`
- Items state changes to `[...[], 'two']`
- Items state changes to `[...[], 'three']`
- Render again and see result

**What is the lifecycle in the solution:**
- render Box
- render Item one
- render Item two
- render Item three
(items state is [] at this point)
- Effect of Item one `setState(prevItems => [...prevItems, 'one'])`
- Effect of Item two `setState(prevItems => [...prevItems, 'two'])`
- Effect of Item three `setState(prevItems => [...prevItems, 'three'])`
- Items state changes to `[...[], 'one']`
- Items state changes to `[...['one'], 'two']`
- Items state changes to `[...['one', 'two'], 'three']`
- Render again and see result

Main point is, when you call setState method, it's not synchronous so change doesn't happen immediately. That's why you have the option to change state depending on previous state with passing a callback function

when `setState(callbackFn)` is executed, react will know that you are trying to construct new state depending on the previous once.
So, whenever you update the state, you should think if you are setting the new state depending on new one. If so, you should use setState function with a callback instead of a value